# Default location for QGIS 3.28 to save shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, storage

I understand that QGIS points to the location of shp layer files. Where are these files saved to by default so that I can find them? I have a Windows 11 PC and laptop.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. It seems you have three questions, one in the title, and two in the body. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There isn't any default location where data is located. It can literally come from anywhere (which is why the path is a property in the layer).

Comment: QGIS doesnt change the location of the files. It is like if you are opening an existing word document in Word. The file is located where you created it originally. Do you mean where are the outputs of geoprocessing operations saved by default? If you just want to find the shapefile location you can [hover](https://imgur.com/a/z3FWe0Z) the pointer on the layer name, or go to Layer Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you type just a filename into save/export dialogs instead of specifying a whole path, it will depend on the working directory in which you launched QGIS.

On a standard Windows installation and launching QGIS via a click on an icon, it will probably be your user's home directory.